# How can I store the xy coords of an agent in NetLogo that I ask to die?

Tags: netlogo

In my model I have a lot of turtles being produced which slows it down. I can get around this by killing them off and having a global counter:

```
ask turtles [
 if energy < 0 [
 set turtle-count turtle-count + 1
 die
  ]]
```

But I'd like to be able to extract the 'who', 'xcor' and 'ycor' of these agents too. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain your context a little bit more? I'm curious why you need the who.

Comment: @mattsap I suppose I don't really, I just want to be able to identify the separate turtles in the output file.

Comment: If you don't, you may want to look into the fly weight pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can save these values in an external file. I suppose this will help you a bit with setting it up, not sure whether you can just copy-paste.

setup the simulation with:

```
to setup
    ....
    set-current-directory user-directory ;;choose directory of file  
    file-open "database.txt" ;;choose any name for your file  


    ask turtles 
    [
         if energy < 0 
         [  
             write-to-file ;;go to the writing section  
             set turtle-count turtle-count + 1  
             die  
         ]
    ]


    ....
end 



to write-to-file  
    file-write who  
    file-write xcor  
    file-write ycor  
    file-print "" ;;new line for next turtle
end
```

end your simulations with

```
file-close-all ;;save the file
```

if you open the txt file it might look like a mess, but import it, for example, in excel with space delimited, and you will be able to read everything nicely

EDIT1

you could also do the following, which might speed up your simulations (rather than asking every turtle an if-function)

```
ask turtles with [energy < 0] 
     [  
         write-to-file ;;go to the writing section  
         set turtle-count turtle-count + 1  
         die  
     ]
```

maybe someone with a bit more experience could comment on whether this is the case?

Comment: there's no appreciable speed difference between `with` and `if`